# How to convert the string into desired format using R?

Tags: r, regex

I have the below string with me:

```
"Names:Cummins, Inc. Cummins Engine Company, Inc.| Variant title:Dodge Ram 24 valve turbo diesel, 2000.0 model year wiring diagram :bull. no. 3666481.|"
```

Using **regular expressions** using R, I need the above string to be converted into the below format:

```
"Names:| Variant title: |"
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want. Do you want to extract the words Names and Variant title, do you need the values, something else? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I need the text after the first occurrence of ":" to be removed till the occurrence of "|". So the program should read "Names:" and remove the text afterwords till "|" is encountered. Similarly read "Variant title:" and remove the text afterwords till "|" is encountered. So finally we would get "Names:| Variant title: |" as the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
text <- c("Names:Cummins, Inc. Cummins Engine Company, Inc.| Variant title:Dodge Ram 24 valve turbo diesel, 2000.0 model year wiring diagram :bull. no. 3666481.|")
gsub("(\\b[A-Z][\\w\\s]+:)[^|]+", "\\1", text, perl = TRUE)
```

This yields

```
[1] "Names:| Variant title:|"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XHmw7H/1).